# Proving that a subset is a subspace of a vector space 3

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

How does one go about proving or disproving that:

$$
\{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)  \in \Bbb{R}^\infty : 
\text{ there is a } k > 1 \text{ such that } a_i = 0 \text{ for all } i \text{ such that } i > k \} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^\infty
$$

is a subspace.

I am not even sure what this set represents so i do not really know how to go about answering this question. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where did you obtain this question from? Thence you may get an idea of what $R^\infty$ is.

Comment: it was a question given to students in a previous exam. That vector space represents an infinite dimensional space consisting of n-tuples that are made up of infinitely many ordered real number. I do not understand what this set represents given the restrictions

Answer (score 0):

The given set is simply the set of all infinite sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of real numbers (that's $\Bbb R^\infty$ so far) with the added condition that they become zero eventually. That is for each such sequence there is some index $k$ such that $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ can be any number, but $a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}, \ldots$ are zero.

Equivalent formulations: This is the set of all sequences such that "*almost all* members are zero", or which have "at most finitely many non-zero members".

To check if this is a subspace is mostly straight-forward. When checking if it is closed under addition, let's say we have $(a_i)$ such that $a_i = 0$ for $i>k_a$ and $(b_i)$ such that $b_i = 0$ for $i>k_b$, note that these conditions stay intact if we replace $k_a$ and $k_b$ by $k := \max\{k_a, k_b\}$.